# Hi I have 25-40 test cases written in appium python but only few test cases are running and server is getting struck after some time

Tags: python-appium

my desired capabilities

```
def __init__(self):
       
   
    caps = {
           'platformName' : 'Android',
           'platformVersion' : '11.0',
           'automationName' : 'uiautomator2',
           'appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages' : True,
           'appium:newCommandTimeout' : 300
        }
        
   
    self.instance=webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', caps)
```

It should run without any halts what am i missing is there any adb settings that i need to do in android studio.?

Answer (score 0):

It depends several factors

- **Resource Exhaustion** - Ensure you have a better device configuration to run tests longer
- **Device/Emulator Issues** -  several tests are device-dependent, high-end devices perform much faster than normal devices
- **Session Cleanup** - Make sure you properly manage and clean up your test sessions